# "push" takes very long time and never seems to end when I push some changes to Github remote repo from VSCode local repo

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, push

I'm coding something in python and tried to push them but it took very very long time and never seems to end, so I raised this issue.

What I succeeded are below;

- Created a new remote repo in Github
- Cloned the repo into local repo by VSCode
- Created a file and saved it in local env
- Staged all the changes and pushed them into local repo by VSCode

Then, I pushed them into remote repo by pressing button below;
[This button which shows 0 pull and 4 pushes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEZ1a.png)

Spec and logs that I found are below;

Windows Specifications

> Edition   Windows 10 Home 
> Version   20H2 
> OS build  19042.1052 
> Experience    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0

Output (Python)

> Python interpreter path: ~\anaconda3\python.exe 
> Error 2021-07-06 21:34:56: Failed to check if file needs to be fixed [EntryNotFound (FileSystemError): Unable to read file 'c:\Users\81906\Documents\atcoder.vscode\settings.json' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'c:\Users\81906\Documents\atcoder.vscode\settings.json') 
> at _handleError (c:\Users\81906\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:84:155535) 
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) 
> at async y.readText (c:\Users\81906.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\out\client\extension.js:9:343940) 
> at async p.doesFileNeedToBeFixed (c:\Users\81906.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\out\client\extension.js:59:581700) 
> at async c:\Users\81906.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\out\client\extension.js:59:580827 
> at async Promise.all (index 1) 
> at async p.getFilesToBeFixed (c:\Users\81906.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\out\client\extension.js:59:580773) 
> at async p.updateTestSettings (c:\Users\81906.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.6.944021595\out\client\extension.js:59:580400)] {
> code: 'FileNotFound'
> }

Output (Git)

> git remote --verbose
> Warning: Failed to watch ref 'c:\Users\81906\Documents\atcoder.git\refs\remotes\origin\main', is most likely packed.

Output (Log (Setting Sync))

> [2021-07-06 21:34:54.005] [settingssync] [info] Using settings sync service https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/
> [2021-07-06 21:34:54.005] [settingssync] [info] Auto Sync is disabled.